# How to save [object Object] in mysql table

Tags: json

I am reading a JSON file and I extract info from it. Here is an example:

```
 "mediaFiles": [{
  "mediaUri": "some.mp3",
  "mediaPath": "something.mp3",
  "startTime": "2018-05-09T03:04:22.000 0000",
  "stopTime": "2018-05-09T03:04:31.000 0000",
  "callUUID": "something",
  "mediaId": "something.mp3.bin",
  "type": "audio/mp3",
  "duration": "9255",
  "tenant": "Environment",
  "ivrprofile": "Record",
  "size": "18144",
  "parameters": {
    "dateTime": "2018-05-09T03:04:47Z",
    "uniqueId": "J2KV33MUT53JTBG0U73CDKC7QS000006",
    "from": "1002",
    "id": "J2KV33MUT53JTBG0U73CDKC7QS000006_2018-05-09_03-04-47_",
    "to": "1001",
    "usered": "Agent2N@somewhere.com"
  },
  "pkcs7": ".. values ...",
  "certAlias": [" ... values....],
  "partitions": [],
  "accessgroups": ["/myagents"]
}],
```

Everything is fine until I reach the **Parameters** object. I have another process which happily extracts them but I can't find a way to exclude them in the `mediafiles` array. Here is a snippet of how I do it:

```
      for (num in J.recordings[x].mediaFiles) {
      mediavalue += Object.values(J.recordings[x].mediaFiles[num]) + 
 "),";
      mediavalue.replace(",[object Object],", ",");
      for (numpara in J.recordings[x].mediaFiles[num].parameters) {
    paradata += "'" + J.recordings[x].mediaFiles[num].parameters[numpara] + "',";

  }
  paradata = paradata.slice(0, -1);
  paradata += temppara;
  savepara(paradata);
}


mediadata += mediavalue;
//   mediadata.slice(12);
// tried to exclude parameters... didnt work
savemedia(mediadata);
```

I need to get all the values in the mediaFiles kvp and put them into an insert statement to save to MySQL. However, the parameters appear as `[object Object]`. I tried excluding them, replacing them and now I'm trying to save them as a blob.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: i'm getting the following in the mediadata variable.
audio/mp3,9255,Environment,Record,18144,[object Object],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need to convert to JSON using [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) before sending it:

```
savemedia(JSON.stringify(mediadata));
```